# Query to shows data on date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have database table form like this:

```
          | ID | Vehicle | Date_start          | Date_end            | Status |
          |  1 | A       | 2021-01-17 12:00:00 | 2021-01-18 13:00:00 | Finish |
          |  2 | B       | 2021-01-19 12:00:00 | 2021-01-21 12:00:00 | In Use |
```

Then, i have code like this:

```
      $datestart = '2021-01-19 '.Date("H:i");
      $dateend = '2021-01-20 '.Date("H:i");
      $cek =Peminjamanrandis::where('status','!=',"Cancel")
             ->where('status','!=','Selesai')
             ->where('status','!=','Pengajuan Peminjaman')
             ->where('status','!=','Tidak Disetujui')
             ->where(function ($query) use($datestart,$dateend) {
               $query->whereBetween('date_start',[$datestart,$dateend])
                     ->orwhereBetween('date_end',[$datestart,$dateend]);
              })
             ->where(function ($query) use($datestart) {
                 $query->where('date_start', '<=', $datestart)
                       ->orWhere('date_start', '>=',$datestart);
             })
             ->where(function ($query) use($dateend) {
                 $query->where('date_end', '<=', $dateend)
                       ->orWhere('date_end', '>=',$dateend);
             })
          ->get(['id_randis']);
```

Then I have a form input that received date start and date end.
Problem : when users input date start = 2021-01-19 and date end = 2021-01-20 or date start =2021-01-20 and date end= 2021-01-20. It shows nothing.

My goals is when user input like that, it shows vehicle B (ID 2). How can I do that?

Comment: wouldn't you want the start date to be the start of the day for that day and the end date to be the end of the day for that day?

Comment: @lagbox start date and end date it depends on users input, i just try case like that and find bug.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.Date("H:i")` by `.Date("H:i:s")`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `whereBetween('column_name in your db table', ['start_date', 'end_date'])`. It usually works like that just make sure same date format in all of date input.

Comment: already try that, it shows nothing too when start date and end date 2021-01-20